# Addition of a matrix using thread in c

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix

The question is to add two matrix using thread,where a loop takes row element of 2 matrix and that thread creates thread to add the individual elements. Below is the code --

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<error.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define r 2
#define c 3
struct mat{
    int (*a)[r][c];
    int (*b)[r][c];
    int (*d)[r][c];
    int m, n;
};
struct element{
    int *a;
    int *b;
    int *d;
};
void* add_element(void* pelement){
    struct element* e1 = pelement;
    (*e1).d = (*e1).a + (*e1).b;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void* add_row(void* pmat){
    struct mat *mat1 = pmat;
    int i = 0, m = mat1->m, n = mat1->n;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        pthread_t add_e;
        struct element e1;
        e1.a = (*mat1->a)[m][i];
        e1.b = (*mat1->b)[m][i];
        e1.d = (*mat1->d)[m][i];
        if(pthread_create(&add_e, NULL, add_element, &e1) != 0){
            perror("Unable to create thread\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        (*mat1->d)[m][i] = e1.d;
        pthread_join(add_e, NULL);
        //(*(*mat1).d)[m][i] = (*(*mat1).a)[m][i] + (*(*mat1).b)[m][i];
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}
int main()
{
    int a[r][c] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int b[r][c] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int d[r][c] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    pthread_t add_mat[r];
    struct mat mat1;
    mat1.a = &a;
    mat1.b = &b;
    mat1.d = &d;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < r; ++i){
        mat1.m = i;
        mat1.n = c;
        if(pthread_create(&add_mat[i], NULL, add_row, &mat1) != 0){
            perror("Unable to create thread\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        pthread_join(add_mat[i], NULL);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < r; ++i){
        int j = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < c; ++j)
            printf("%d ", d[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

While executing, I am doing something wrong with the pointer. The error is like --

```
add_matrix.c: In function ‘add_element’:
add_matrix.c:20:20: error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘int *’ and ‘int *’)
  (*e1).d = (*e1).a + (*e1).b;
```

How can I handle the pointer in order to get the result?
**Edit**
I have solved it. Please ignore it.

Comment: Why have you `int *` into `element` looks like you want `int`

Comment: Yes, Now I got my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.